# transform numbers in href tel tag

Tags: regex

I have a directory with hundreds of phone numbers with the form "xx.xx.xx.xx.xx".
where "x" are numbers from 0 to 9. Groups of 2 numbers are seaparated by a dot. 
I'm looking for a regex that would integrate the last 9 numbers in a syntax like this

```
<a href="tel:+33XXXXXXXXX">xx.xx.xx.xx.xx</a>
```

The +33 is the French International extension that replaces the first number that always starts by 0. 
I would like to keep the original format between the tags if possible.

Comment: Could you give an example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What language/tool are you using?  Please considering posting this Question on the sister site https://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, if you want to check official france-number:

`^(?:(?:\+|00)33|0)\.[1-9](?:[\.]\d{2}){4}$`

So you can enter a number with `+33.6.11.22.33.44`, or with `0033.6.11 22.33.44` and both will matches.

I hope this is what you are searching